# Raspberry pi 3 not reading SD cards

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+

I have a raspberry pi 3 v1.2 that is not reading SD cards. I DO have another pi 3, and that one reads and boots with the SD card in question without any issues whatsoever. On the working pi, I can insert the sd card and on the boot, the green light blinks showing activity - on the pi 3 with problems, the red light for power comes on but no green blinking light or other output. I have also tried multiple other SD cards to no effect.

The SD card is NOT the issue.

What can I test or check on the Raspberry Pi to get it running again? **Is there any way to boot a pi without any SD card?**

Comment: What is shown on monitor when you power up with no SD Card?

Comment: normally, the green light blinks in a pattern if there is an issue. is it blinking in a pattern?